Stiefel-Whitney Classes for Physicists
I am a theoretical physicist and i am trying to understand better how spin structure works. I understand fairly decently Riemannian geometry but have little to zero knowledge of algebraic/differential topology.
I'm studying spin structures on Riemannian manifolds and i found that Stiefel-Whitney (SW) classes are related to this.
In particular i found that the vanishing of the first SW class tells me if my manifold is orientable, while the vanishing of the second SW class tells me if it admits a spin structure.
Having very little knowledge on topology which is not the usual basic stuff, how can i understand what such classes even mean?
Can you explain me SW classes like i knew nothing about them?
Bonus points if you can make some examples of manifolds with vanishing and not vanishing 1-2 SW classes.

Do you know what cohomology is?

No, i understand homology, but i have not done yet the jump to cohomology, hence my lack of understanding
